# jQuery: Calculate multidimensional array by keyname

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, css-selectors, inputbox

i've confused how to do calculation in javascript while using multidimensional array, i have form like this

```html
<input type=number name="sell['FRUIT']['YELLOW']">
<input type=number name="stock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" value=100 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['WOOD']['BLACK']">
<input type=number name="stock['WOOD']['BLACK']" value=50 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['WOOD']['BLACK']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['RED']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" value=25 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" value=40 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" disabled>
```

that FRUIT/WOOD/VEGETABLE and COLOR Keys are Dinamicaly generated from PHP, it can be anything, but will have same key and subkey on that **sell**, **stock** and **newstock** array.

What i need to do is calculate and put the value on **newstock** input box by substracting **stock** with **sell** from user input.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have the list of array dimensions (fruit/wood/veg / yellow/black/reg/green) outside the `name=` property?  Are you able to amend the HTML?  (is it yours or a 3rd party)?

Comment: yes i have, because i generated that from php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either be careful with the quotes or use [`jQuery.escapeSelector`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/):

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name^="sell"]').on("change", function() {
    var name2 = this.name.replace(/^sell/, "stock");
    var name3 = this.name.replace(/^sell/, "newstock");
    var diff = $('input[name="' + $.escapeSelector(name2) + '"]').val() - $(this).val();
               $('input[name="' + $.escapeSelector(name3) + '"]').val(diff);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=number name="sell['FRUIT']['YELLOW']">
<input type=number name="stock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" value=100 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['WOOD']['BLACK']">
<input type=number name="stock['WOOD']['BLACK']" value=50 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['WOOD']['BLACK']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['RED']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" value=25 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" value=40 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" disabled>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event handler to the `input` and update the specific input like this:

- `newStockName` gets the input's name you want to update using the current input's name
- `$(this).next().val() - $(this).val()` gets the difference between the `stock` input and the current `sell` input being changed

```js
$("input").change(function() {
  const newStockName = this.name.replace("sell", "newstock");
  const difference = $(this).next().val() - $(this).val();
  $(`input[name="${newStockName}"]`).val(difference)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=number name="sell['FRUIT']['YELLOW']">
<input type=number name="stock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" value=100 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['WOOD']['BLACK']">
<input type=number name="stock['WOOD']['BLACK']" value=50 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['WOOD']['BLACK']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['RED']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" value=25 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" disabled>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']">
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" value=40 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't have a "multi-dimension" array, you have a name property with text that matches 3 inputs together, as in:

```
(sell|stock|newstock)(.*?)
```

if you could set classes/data against each input, it would be much easier, eg:

```
<input type=number class='sell' data-key1="FRUIT" data-key2="YELLOW">
```

without this, you can get the same thing, just by parsing the `name=` attribute.

Loop through each `sell` to get the key, get matching stock/newstock inputs and update.

One issue is that your name includes `[`, `]` and `'` which cause issues with the jquery selector, so you need to escape these first.

```js
//alert($("[name=stock\\[\\'FRUIT\\'\\]\\[\\'YELLOW\\'\\]]").length)

$("#btn").click(function() {
  var sell = $("[name^=sell]");

  sell.each(function() {
    // Get key and "fix" for jquery selector (alternate regex possible, simple version here)
     var key = $(this).attr("name").substr(4).replace(/\[/g, "\\[").replace(/\]/g, "\\]").replace(/\'/g, "\\'");

    // find matching stock
    var stock = $("[name=stock" + key + "]").val() * 1;

    var newstock = stock - $(this).val() * 1;

    $("[name=newstock" + key + "]").val(newstock);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type=number name="sell['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" value=5>
<input type=number name="stock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" value=100 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['FRUIT']['YELLOW']" disabled>
<hr/>

<input type=number name="sell['WOOD']['BLACK']" value=5>
<input type=number name="stock['WOOD']['BLACK']" value=50 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['WOOD']['BLACK']" disabled>
<hr/>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['RED']" value=5>
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" value=25 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['RED']" disabled>
<hr/>

<input type=number name="sell['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" value=5>
<input type=number name="stock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" value=40 disabled>
<input type=number name="newstock['VEGETABLE']['GREEN']" disabled>
<hr/>

<button id='btn'>calc</button>
```